# Visual c# Replace special characters and white space from a string

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I want to replace the white space and special characters with a hyphen.

I want to all the non-letters characters with a hyphen like ?,(,),{,},[,],<,>,",',!,@<# etc

Comment: In all seriousness - please attempt to solve your own problems first.  If you don't succeed - then please post your questions on here and provide what you have tried along with code samples.

Comment: And the problem that you are having is what exactly?

Comment: What do you mean by "special characters"?

Comment: sorry for not giving you the full details

Answer (score 2):

This would do all non-alpha-numeric and non-whitespace characters:

```
var input = "this i$ s@m3 inp^t";
var replaced = Regex.Replace(input, @"[^\d\w\s]","-");
Console.WriteLine(replaced);
// Output: this i- s-m3 inp-t
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you define "special characters", you can just do:

```
yourString = Regex.Replace(yourString,@"\W","-");
```